# How to subtract values by group (subtract blank stored as one group) using dplyr?

Tags: r, transform, tidyverse, dplyr

I have some tidy data, and one of the group is a blank:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3), "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"), 
                 ID = rep(1:3, 4),
                 Value = c(10, 11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 1, 2, 3))    
df
   Group ID Value
1      A  1    10
2      B  2    11
3      C  3    12
4      A  1    21
5      B  2    22
6      C  3    23
7      A  1    31
8      B  2    32
9      C  3    33
10 Blank  1     1
11 Blank  2     2
12 Blank  3     3
```

I wanted to subtract `Blank` from each group (A, B, C), so the normalized data will look like that:

```
df_normalized<- data.frame(Group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3),
             ID = rep(1:3, 3),
             Value = c(9, 9, 9, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30))

df_normalized
  Group ID Value
1     A  1     9
2     B  2     9
3     C  3     9
4     A  1    20
5     B  2    20
6     C  3    20
7     A  1    30
8     B  2    30
9     C  3    30
```

How to do it nicely using dplyr?

EDIT: 
How to do that for multiple groups? e.g:

```
df <- data.frame(Cluster = c(rep("C1", 12), rep("C2", 12)),
                 Group = rep(c(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 3), "Blank", "Blank", "Blank"), 2), 
                 ID = rep(1:3, 8),
                 Value = sample(24))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you'll have only one "Blank" value per `ID` as shown in the example, you can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Value = Value - Value[Group == "Blank"])  %>%
  filter(Group != "Blank")

#  Group    ID Value
#  <fct> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         1     9
#2 B         2     9
#3 C         3     9
#4 A         1    20
#5 B         2    20
#6 C         3    20
#7 A         1    30
#8 B         2    30
#9 C         3    30
```

If you have more than one "Blank" you can use `match` which would ensure that only the first value is selected.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Value = Value - Value[match("Blank", Group)])  %>%
  filter(Group != "Blank")
```

Comment: Thanks! That pretty much solves the problem :)  But how to do that for multiple groups (see edit of the original question)?

Comment: @Art Not sure if I am missing something but wouldn't that be just adding `Cluster` in `group_by` ?  `df %>% group_by(ID, Cluster) %>%....` Or do you expect something else as output ?

Comment: Oh true, sure! I was trying that in my real data but for some totally other reason didn't work. But working OK on the example! Thanks again for help!